# Problem in fetching http get request after put float number

Tags: arduino-uno, c, http

I have this codes that works correctly!

```c
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define PIN_TX    7
#define PIN_RX    8
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX,PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,
char http_cmd[] = "GET /index.php?lat=*******&long=******* HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                        "Host: 04d1a36d.ngrok.io\r\n"
                        "\r\n";
char buffer[512];

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!sim808.init())
  {
      Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
      delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.print("Sim808 init Success\r\n");
  delay(3000);

  //*********** Attempt DHCP *******************
  while(!sim808.join(F("cmnet"))) {
      Serial.println("Sim808 join network error");
      delay(2000);
  }                        

  //************ Successful DHCP ****************
  Serial.print("IP Address is ");
  Serial.println(sim808.getIPAddress());

  //*********** Establish a TCP connection ************
  while(!sim808.connect(TCP,"39c309ae.ngrok.io", 80)) {
      Serial.println("Connect error");
  }
  Serial.println("Connection success");


  //*********** Send a GET request *****************
  Serial.println("waiting to fetch...");
  sim808.send(http_cmd, sizeof(http_cmd)-1);
  while (true) {
      int ret = sim808.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
      if (ret <= 0){
          Serial.println("fetch over...");
          break; 
      }
      buffer[ret] = '\0';
      Serial.print("Recv: ");
      Serial.print(ret);
      Serial.print(" bytes: ");
      Serial.println(buffer);
      break;
  }

  //************* Close TCP or UDP connections **********
  sim808.close();

  //*** Disconnect wireless connection, Close Moving Scene *******
  sim808.disconnect();
  delay(5000);  
  }
  void loop(){
  }
```

Actually i want send two numbers instead of ****** in this line:

```c
char http_cmd[] = "GET /index.php?lat=*******&long=******* HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                        "Host: 04d1a36d.ngrok.io\r\n"
                        "\r\n";
```

to 04d1a642.ngrok.io/index.php for inserting in a database.

but when i use

> sprintf

like this:

```c
void setup(){
sprintf( http_cmd, "GET /index.php?lat=%f&long=%f HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                        "Host: 04d1a662.ngrok.io\r\n"
                        "\r\n", 36.423156, 48.526484);
.
.
.
```

The module doesn't fetch to server for get response!

Comment: Don't use `sizeof(...)`, use `strlen(...)`. Also Arduino cannot use floats in sprintf.

Comment: @Majenko - so how i can send float numbers as Get request to my server?

Comment: You can use `dtostrf()` to convert from a float to a char array.

Comment: `?` is inserted instead of the float value with sprintf.

Comment: print the string to serial ... see if it is valid

Comment: I'm not actually professional in arduino and c! can you help ?